# How to intersect two select with int and string type in LINQ Method syntax?

Tags: c#

I am new to programming I hope you can help me to write better code.

**Description**

I want to write a query that prints Average scores of Californians who are active and have the letter R or D in their name.

**Example Input**

```
StudentName = {"Ben Wild", Score = 65, StudentCity = "CA", StudentActvity= true}

StudentName = {"Sara Ride", Score = 81, StudentCity = "CA", StudentActvity = true}
```

**My problem**

I need to select their name and their score at the end but I can't select two Lambda expressions and `&&` them together.
I got this error : `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Score' and no accessible extension method 'Score' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be`

I tried so many ways that I will mention my solutions below :

**Program.cs code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace _64_LINQ_Practice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Access to the class method
            var studentList = StudentDatabase.GetStudentsFromDb();
            var studentsName6 = studentList.Where(x => (x.StudentActvity == true) && (x.StudentCity == "CA")).Select(x => x.StudentName);
            List<string> xstudent = new List<string>(studentList.Select(x => x.StudentName));
            IEnumerable<string> final = xstudent.Where(
                                x => x.Contains("R") || x.Contains("r") || x.Contains("d") || x.Contains("D"));

            foreach (string studentFinal in final)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The students that are active, live in CA and names with r/R or D/d letter :" + studentFinal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**and second way:**

```
        var studentsName6 = studentList.Where(x => (x.StudentActvity == true) && (x.StudentCity == "CA")).Average(x => x.Score);
        List<string> xstudent = new List<string>(studentList.Select(x => x.StudentName));
        List<int> intstudent = new List<int>(studentList.Select(x => x.Score));
        IEnumerable<string> final = xstudent.Where(
                            x => x.Contains("R") || x.Contains("r") || x.Contains("d") || x.Contains("D"));
        IEnumerable<int> final2 = intstudent;
        var convFinal = final.AsQueryable();
        var convFinal2 = final2.AsQueryable();
        var final3 = studentsName6.AsQueryable().Concat(convFinal.AsQueryable()).Concat(convFinal2);
        var final4 = final3.average(x => x.Score);
        Console.WriteLine(final4);
```

Comment: C# ain't JavaScript, mate. You gotta convert.

Comment: @ValerijDobler You're right, so is there any simple way to do this using convert ? my solution is complicated.

Comment: Simple way to do what? The question is unclear - a lot of text but no concrete question, no original and expected. The `Main` method only contains 3 simple queries. Are you asking how to combine multiple conditions? Chain `Where` clauses. The question seems to only need a single `Where` though. There's no attempt to write a query that calculates averages

Comment: Is the query how to calculate aggregates like averages? You need `GroupBy` and one of the many aggergate functions like `Avg`, `Sum`, `Count` etc. All the conditions you described can go into a single `Where`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm so sorry. I've edited the question, does it look more clear now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no attempt to calculate averages in the code so it's unclear what the problem is. Going by

> prints the average score of students, with these conditions: Average score of students that live in CA and their activity is true and  there are R/r or D/d letters contain in their name.

It seems a single `Where` is needed to filter the students, then `Avg` to calculate the average. Since there's no need to calculate averages for multiple groups, `GroupBy` isn't needed.

```
var letters=new[]{"r","d"};
var average=studentList.Where(st=>
        st.StudentActvity 
        && st.StudentCity == "CA"
        && letters.Any(l=>st.StudentName.Contains(l,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     )
    .Average(st=>st.Score);
```

[String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) can accept a parameter that specifies case-insensitive comparison, so there's no need to specify both small and capital letters.

`letters.Any(l=>st.StudentName.Contains(l...))` checks if any letter is contained inside `StudentName`

This query will work with an in-memory database and probably an actual database. It will be very slow though. `name.Contains("r")` is translated to the SQL condition `name LIKE '%r%'`. There's no way to use an index to quickly find which names have `r` in their middle, so the database will have to search the entire table

Comment: Thank you so muh. the answer to average is right although you didn't use  `st.StudentActvity == true
                    && st.StudentCity == "CA"`   here.  so the condition of r/d name should be checked first.

Comment: I don't have to. `st.StudentActivity` is a boolean value, so `st.StudentActvity == true` is equivalent to just `st.StudentActvity`

Comment: As for `the condition of r/d name should be checked first.` the order doesn't affect the outcome in an `AND` clause. The entire statement is true only if all statements are true. The order can affect performance in in-memory evaluation but a database won't try to evaluate these conditions for every row. If possible, it will use indexes to quickly find the set of rows that match the condition.

Comment: Thanks. yes when I tried I got error. that was one of my problems too, I didn't know there is no need to write the value of activity.